# IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [table] and [servletbasic.MakeTable] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MakeTable]

Tags: tomcat, servlets, mapping

I have a problem when start Tomcat v7.0.

```
'Staring Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
 Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

I found that my the problem was in web.xml file.
This file looks like this

```
<display-name>Exercises</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>table</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletbasic.MakeTable</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>table</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MakeTable</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when i **removed servlet-mapping tag, Tomcat started well**.
Here is my project tree

```
  ---Java Resources

    ---servletbasic

      ---MakeTable.java
```

I tried changing http port number, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: post full tomcat server log.

Comment: thks. it is too long, i post it below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your logs :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named
>   [table] and [servletbasic.MakeTable] are both mapped to the
>   url-pattern [/MakeTable] which is not permitted

It seems that you have two servlet `table` and `MakeTable` which are mapping to the same URL `/MakeTable`.

This may be caused by mixing two servlet declaration method by `annotation-based` using `@WebServlet` annotation in your servlet class and by `web.xml-based` configuration same as you have posted.

Comment: thank you so much. I changed /MakeTable to different name and it worked.

Comment: @user3455969 you might want to accept this answer then! (and probably upvote it too)